# Raspberry PI - Google Home SDK Security Handshake Error

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

Thanks very much for reading my post

Have raspberry pi 3B
Running RASPBIAN JESSIE WITH DESKTOP.

Followed these instructions to get Google Assistance working
https://www.hackster.io/Salmanfarisvp/g ... -pi-9f3677

Then these to get hotword setup
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436 ... spberry-pi

Upon running command 'googlesamples-assistant-hotword' I often get the below errors, other times google home will work for awhile only to give these errors then fail

```
E0723 00:23:58.518779664    2744 handshake.c:128]            Security handshake failed: {"created":"@1500726238.518626644","description":"Handshake read failed","file":"../../third_party/grpc/src/core/lib/security/transport/handshake.c","file_line":237,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1500726238.518608103","description":"FD shutdown","file":"../../third_party/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/ev_epoll_linux.c","file_line":1045}]}
[2727:2744:ERROR:speech_recognition_activity.cc(550)] S3 connection has timed out: No data from S3
ON_ASSISTANT_ERROR:
  {u'is_fatal': False}
[2727:2744:ERROR:assistant_output_handler.cc(618)] Failed with a general speech recognition error
Segmentation fault
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: hey @UglyBobNZ did you find any solution for this issue?

Comment: Alfonso from the Assistant SDK team here. We believe this is an issue that occurs with slow or spotty connections, and we will try to fix it in a future release. Can you check on a better network and confirm if this still happens every time?